# How to query range of data in DB2 with highest performance?

Tags: sql, database, pagination, db2

Usually, I need to retrieve data from a table in some range; for example, a separate page for each search result. In MySQL I use LIMIT keyword but in DB2 I don't know. Now I use this query for retrieve range of data.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
   SELECT  
      SMALLINT(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME DESC)) AS RUNNING_NO
      , DATA_KEY_VALUE
      , SHOW_PRIORITY
   FROM 
      EMPLOYEE
   WHERE 
      NAME LIKE 'DEL%'
   ORDER BY
      NAME DESC
   FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
) AS TMP
ORDER BY 
  TMP.RUNNING_NO ASC
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

but I know it's bad style. So, how to query for highest performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My requirement have been added into DB2 9.7.2 already.

DB2 9.7.2 adds new syntax for limit query result as illustrate below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 5 OFFSET 20
```

the database will retrieve result from row no. 21 - 25

Comment: I think 'LIMIT' only works if MySQL compatibility is enabled? Running DB2 9.7.3 does not seem to support this by default (SQL0104N  An unexpected token "LIMIT" was found following "".)

Comment: Yes; it works in the DB2 9.7.4. This is an article it talks about this new feature: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1006db2expressc972/index.html

Comment: In seems that it only works for DB2 Express-C and you have to change the compatibility_vector to mys, as it is explained in the article.

Comment: You really shouldn't use this `MySQL` syntax in DB2, if you can avoid it. Better use [DB2's own paging syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/273106/521799)...

Answer (score 6):

It's very difficult, it is depends which database do you have.

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID_USER ASC) AS ROWNUM,  
      ID_EMPLOYEE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
    FROM EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE 'DEL%' 
  )  AS A WHERE A.rownum
BETWEEN 1 AND 25
```

Comment: I observed latency of close to 10 seconds for 2.3 million records. Reason for upvote is it worked without changing core database settings. :)

Comment: Does this work on Union of two tables. Please suggest the changes because ROW_NUMBER() should be added to all queries of the union. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you are creating the TMP table.  Isn't RUNNING_NO aready in ascending sequence?  I would think:

```
SELECT SMALLINT(RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME DESC)) AS RUNNING_NO,
       DATA_KEY_VALUE,
       SHOW_PRIORITY
  FROM EMPLOYEE
 WHERE NAME LIKE 'DEL%'
 ORDER BY NAME DESC
 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

would give the same results.

Having an INDEX over NAME on the EMPLOYEE table will boost performance of this query.

Comment: Hey, @Paul, this is a great example! Thank you. Is the `ORDER BY NAME DESC` redundant in the outer query?

Comment: probably so but I'm just copying his example without the tmp table.  Could use just DESC instead.

Comment: Is there a way to specify offset and range ?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, to make a pagination just follow the syntax.

```
LIMIT (pageSize) OFFSET ((currentPage) * (pageSize))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it with DB2's own paging syntax, do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME DESC) AS RUNNING_NO,
        DATA_KEY_VALUE, SHOW_PRIORITY
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE NAME LIKE 'DEL%'
    ORDER BY NAME DESC
    )
WHERE RUNNING_NO > (:page_no - 1) * :page_size
FETCH FIRST :page_size ROWS ONLY;
```