# implementing paging logic in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, pagination, db2

Is there a way to implement paging logic in DB2 SQL, where records can be fetched page wise.
The following query works only for queries with no joins. When queries with join are used the ROW_NUM is returned as 0 and paging cannot be done.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER() AS ROW_NUM, Results.*
                         FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 ) AS Results) AS PagedResults
WHERE PagedResults.ROW_NUM>0 AND PagedResults.ROW_NUM<=10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May provide query with join example?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER() AS ROW_NUM, Results.*
                         FROM (SELECT * FROM  F12 INNER JOIN  F13 ON F12.ID=F13.ID ) AS Results) AS PagedResults

Comment: Throw me a bone here anyone... I am implementing this using temporary table. There's a better way than this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query range of data in DB2 with highest performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265850/how-to-query-range-of-data-in-db2-with-highest-performance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to query range of data in DB2 with highest performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265850/how-to-query-range-of-data-in-db2-with-highest-performance)

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, then I guess the question should be closed as a duplicate...