# Efficient DB2 query pagination and show total pages?

Tags: mysql, performance, pagination, db2, resultset

This post shows some hacks to page data from DB2:

[How to query range of data in DB2 with highest performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265850/how-to-query-range-of-data-in-db2-with-highest-performance)

However it does not provide a way to show the total number of rows (like MySQL's CALC_FOUND_ROWS).

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS thread_id AS id, name, email
FROM threads WHERE email IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 200
```

And in MySQL I can follow that up with

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

to get the total number of rows. The first part is fairly easy to duplicate with recent versions of DB2. I can't find any results on Google for a reasonable equivalent to the second query (I don't want temp tables, subqueries, or other absurdly inefficient solutions).

Comment: BTW, I"m using very recent DB2, so any new features would be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this exists in DB2.

Note that the total number of rows is a value that needs extra calculation to obtain.  It isn't just lying around somewhere--it would have to be specifically built into the `LIMIT` logic.  Which it doesn't look like they did.

Comment: So, I would just need to repeat a modified query with a count(*) then, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @sventech, yeah, getting the count in a separate query would probably be best.

Comment: Refer below answer,        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997838/fastest-most-efficient-way-to-do-pagination-with-sql-searching-db2